# Existence of weak* limit of weak cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $\{x_{n} \}$ be a weakly Cauchy sequence in a normed linear space $X$. Then, there exists $x^{**}$ in $X^{**}$ such that $x_{n}$ converges weak* to $x^{**}$ and $\|x^{**}\| \leq \lim\inf_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|$.

**My attempt:** Since $x_{n}$ is weakly Cauchy, in the viewpoint of $X^{**}$, it is weak* Cauchy, thus, from boundedness of norm of $x_{n}$, and any closed ball is compact by the Alaoglu's theorem, there exists $x^{**}$ such that $x_{n} \to x^{**}$ in weak star sense.

However, I don't know how to show that $\|x^{**}\| \leq \lim\inf_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|$. Could you give me a hint to approach this problem?

Comment: It is a weakly Cauchy sequence, not a net?

Comment: Your application of Alaoglu is not clear to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Alaoglu.

Since $(x_n)$ is weakly Cauchy, for every $x^*\in X^*$ the sequence $(x^*(x_n))$ is Cauchy, hence convergent. So we can define $$x^{**}:X^*\to\mathbb C$$by $$x^{**}(x^*)=\lim_nx^*(x_n).$$

Uniform boundedness shows that $||x_n||$ is  bounded, hence $x^{**}$ is bounded. And $$|x^{**}(x^*)|=\liminf|x^*(x_n)|\le\liminf||x^*||\,||x_n||
=(\liminf||x_n||)(||x^*||),$$ so $||x^{**}||\le\liminf||x_n||$.

Comment: Wow, I thought in wrong way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\forall\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $x^*\in X^*$ with $\|x^*\|=1$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\|x^{**}\|-\varepsilon\leq |x^{**}(x^*)|=\lim_{n} |x_n(x^*)|\leq \liminf_{n}\|x_n\|.
\end{align*}
The last inequality is because $|x_n(x^*)|\leq \|x_n\|\forall n$.

Hence, $ \|x^{**}\|\leq\liminf_{n}\|x_n\|$.